# Chrome plugin/extension with opening new tabs and fill out with external data

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, automation

I am interested in creating chrome extension that will be working as automation tool. I want to pass to that extension json object with some data with specific actions:

1. open new tab
2. go to url
3. fill out form (with data passed to extension)
4. submitting forms

I was searching for similar solutions but they are available as plugin dedicated for users, not for developers. Also i am not sure if chrome api handles all of that or if some helpfull libraries are not already exists.

Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Unclear: do you want to make that an extension for others to use, or for yourself? What's the intended goal? Why is "plugin dedicated for users, not for developers" bad?

Comment: @Xan i wan't to use it only for restricted group of users that will be allowed to sign into my cms and to download that extension together with my cms. Extension can't work separately and can't be downloaded from other sources then my cms.

Comment: Yes, this can be done with an extension (except privately hosting it unless you have an enterprise install of Chrome). So what's your question to be answered here?

Comment: I am searching for tools, mechanism, snippets to achieve listed above actions.

Comment: Then that is [off-topic or too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), take your pick. Don't word it as "suggest a library", that's off-topic. Focus the question on a particular aspect, and it won't be too broad.